# Area of rectangle from area of square?

Tags: area, rectangles

The definition of [area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#Formal_definition) usually include the area of a rectangle definition. Can one replace it with "the area of a square of side $a$ is $a^2$"? That is can one find the area of a rectangle in this case?

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/350475/1508). Basically, you start with the axiom that the area of a $1\times 1$ square is $1$, and use further axioms to extend the definition of area to arbitrary rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen something like this in a textbook.  Take a square and add $2$ lines to form smaller squares in opposite corners and 2 congruent rectangles.  If the length of a side of one of the inner squares is $a$ and one of the other inner square is $b$, the outer square has sides of length $a+b$.  So if you take the area of the outer square, subtract the areas of the other squares, and divide by $2$, you should get the area of one of the rectangles with sides of length $a$ and $b$.

$$\frac{(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2}2=\frac{2ab}2=ab$$