# Why is the area of a rectangle given as $l\times h$?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, definition, area, axioms

While this may seem like a simple question, I have found it very difficult to answer.

My question is

> "Why is the area of a rectangle given as $l\times h$?"

We define area as the "size of a two dimensional surface".

I can show with calculus and some geometry that a rectangle with some height $h$ and length $l$, the area of that rectangle is

$$\int_0^lhdx=l\times h$$

But I feel this is circular because we can't really define an integral until we know the area of a rectangle as being $l\times h$.

Using other geometric shapes is also circular because many of them come from either the area of a rectangle or the area of a triangle, which the area of triangle comes from the area of a rectangle!

Perhaps this could be one of those axioms or definitions, it could very well be the definition of area, but if not, could someone show, mathematically or in a proof that the area of a rectangle is given as $l\times h$?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/350475/1508) to a similar question.

Comment: You can fix a unit square and than make assumptions (or axioms) about equal area for congruent shapes, invariance under "reasonable" (certainly not Banach-Tarski-like, for example only by finitely many straight lines) decomposition, and positiveness.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800699) question.